# Condition in jsx and map of an array

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have the following scheme to render my menu and my drop menu:

```
const MenuBar = props => {
  const MenuTags = [
    {
      name: 'home',
      redirectTo: '/',
      dropdown: {
        items: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'about',
      redirectTo: '../about',
      dropdown: {
        items: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
      },
    },
    { name: 'not dropdown', redirectTo: '../dashboard' },
    { name: 'not dropdown', redirectTo: '../dashboard/about' },
  ];
  const [visibleMenu, setVisibleMenu] = useState(
      MenuTags.reduce((r, e) => ((r[e.name] = false), r), {}),
    ),
    onUpdateVisibility = item => {
      const visibleMenuCopy = { ...visibleMenu };
      Object.keys(visibleMenuCopy).forEach(
        key => (visibleMenuCopy[key] = key == item),
      );
      setVisibleMenu(visibleMenuCopy);
    };
  console.log(visibleMenu);
  return (
    <NavUl isOpen={props.isOpen}>
      {MenuTags.map(item => (
        <MenuItem
          options={item}
          visibleMenu={visibleMenu}
          onClick={() => onUpdateVisibility(item)}
        />
      ))}
      <li>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          onClick={() => props.setOpenBox(!props.isOpen)}
          className="searchIcon"
          rotation={90}
          icon={faSearch}
          size="1x"
          fixedWidth
          color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);"
        />
      </li>
    </NavUl>
  );
};
```

basically here i have an array where i have the names that will render in my li and also the redirectLink (to use in the react router link)

```
const MenuItem = props => {
  const { name, redirectTo, dropdown } = props.options;
  return (
    <NavLi>
      <Link to={redirectTo}>{name}</Link>
      {dropdown && dropdown !== null ? <DropDown {...props} /> : ''}
    </NavLi>
  );
};
```

Here I basically render my menu item read and if the dropdown variable is true I will render the following component:

```
const DropDown = props => {
  const { items } = props;
  console.log(props.visibleMenu);
  return(
    <>
    { items && items !== null && props.visibleMenu ?

    }
    </>
  )
};
```

And so here I would check some conditions in jsx and also use the .map in my items array to render the following components:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a>
</li>
</ul>
```

for each item in the array
Well I don't know if my code is good or strange
If anyone can help me with this and how to improve the code

Comment: Could you arrange the problem info in the first place of the total question?

Comment: Ok basically the problem is how to make a conditional in jsx and map an array

and I also asked about my code structure

Comment: I tried to explain according to each component because if I don't think I would be very confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is a great attempt but theres a few strange things you are doing.
Instead of going about everything with a class take advantage of the how react renders each time with state. You don't need this many classes.
This piece here for example:

```
const [visibleMenu, setVisibleMenu] = useState(
      MenuTags.reduce((r, e) => ((r[e.name] = false), r), {}),
    ),
    onUpdateVisibility = item => {
      const visibleMenuCopy = { ...visibleMenu };
      Object.keys(visibleMenuCopy).forEach(
        key => (visibleMenuCopy[key] = key == item),
      );
      setVisibleMenu(visibleMenuCopy);
    };
```

It's quite confusing to read and if I was given a pull request by one of my devs I would reject it.
Like I said take advantage of the rendering react has.
Another thing take advantage of having a self contained piece MenuBar doesn't need to know if dropdownItems are visible or invisible.
Link can be renamed too :)

```
// No need for a class here an array will work great!
const menuTags = [
  { name: 'home', link: '/', dropdownItems: ['one', 'two', 'three'] },
  // ... other menu tags you had.
]

const MenuBar = props => {
  return (
    <NavUl isOpen={props.isOpen}>
      {menuTags.map(menuTag => <MenuTag tag={menuTag} />)
      <li>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          // Move the logic to only be in the Parent, this component shouldn't have to
          // pass it's parents variables.
          onClick={props.toggleOpen}
          // ... the rest of what you had
        />
      </li>
    </NavUl >
  )
}
```

Now that piece cleaned up more of the logic can be moved to the MenuItem itself. Also you don't really need a DropDown file that can be handled in the MenuItem.
I noticed you also did `if (dropdown && dropdown !== null)` that is the same `if (dropdown)`. If a variable is null it be false in javascript.
Another thing is if you want to render something on a react if statement`? <Dropdown /> : ''` you can do this instead `&& <Dropdown />`

```
const MenuItem = ({ tag }) => {
  const { name, link, dropdownItems } = tag;
  // Dropdown visibility can be handled here.
  const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState(false)

  return (
    <NavLi onClick={() => setVisibility(!visibility)} >
      <Link to={link}>{name}</Link>
      // If these are true dropdown items will appear.
      {visibility && dropdownItem && (
        {dropdownItems.map(item => (
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a>{item}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      )}
    </NavLi>
  );
};
```

That should be what you are after.

Comment: hello I'm sorry for the delay
regarding my state i did it this way because i can only have a single state as true when one is true all the others will be false.